# Diverging integral in massive fermionic field correlator

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fermions, dirac-equation, correlation-functions, propagator

I'd like to understand the concept of the 2-particle quantum correlator for massive fermions with mass $m>0$ in 1 spatial dimension: $$C(x,y)=\langle 0|\psi(x)\psi^{\dagger}(y)|0\rangle=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\mathrm{d}p\frac{p\gamma^{3}+m\gamma^1}{\sqrt{p^2+m^2}}e^{-ip(x-y)}.$$ While the term in $\gamma^1$ is well defined since the integral converges and is given by the modified Bessel function $K_0(m|x-y|)$, I can't make sense of the first term in $\gamma^3$ since the integral
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\mathrm{d}p\frac{p}{\sqrt{p^2+m^2}}e^{-ip(x-y)}
\end{align}
does not converge. How is one supposed to fix this?

Comment: $\frac{d}{dx}e^{ip(x-y)}=ip e^{ip(x-y)}$

Comment: @JeanbaptisteRoux: this requires to exchange the derivative with the integral sign. How to justify this? The integral is not absolutely convergent and therefore one is not allowed to use Lebesgue's dominated convergence or, equivalently, the Leibniz's rule for parametric integrals

Comment: Well, I would say that in the first place, your propagator is in the position representation and that using Fourier Transform is the first manipulation you have done, maybe this is not a wise choice. Using Mathematica, I don't see any problem in evaluating this integral, though; further, it gives the same result as the manipulation I've suggested. It seems to me that your question is more mathematics-oriented, and I would recommend you ask your question at [Maths.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions)

Comment: Basic measure theory is not enough to correctly interpret/understand such integrals.
The proper setting is that of temperate Schwartz distributions, their Fourier transforms, and the notions of singular support. Assuming $y=0$ for simplicity, the integral is a well defined temperate distribution in the $x$ variable with singular support given by the set $\{x\neq 0\}$. That means one can evaluate it pointwise for nonzero $x$. A hack to do this is to integrate on $[-A,A]$, using integration by parts to show the limit $A\rightarrow\infty$ converges...

Comment: ...The basic trick to get started is $e^{-ipx}=\frac{i}{x}\frac{\partial}{\partial p}e^{-ipx}$.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam: thank you! I agree that this is the right way to go. I'll have to understand the details now

Comment: Above, I meant to say the singular support is $\{x=0\}$ instead of $\{x\neq 0\}$.